# SQL query to count comments for node type

Tags: 7, comments

I am looking for a SQL query to count all comments for a specific node type. What code should I use to achieve it?

Comment: Please share with us what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this helper function

```
function mymodule_get_comment_count_by_node_type($node_type) {
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
      ->entityCondition('bundle', $node_type, '=')
      ->execute();
  $nids = array_keys($result['node']);

  $comments = db_select('comment', 'c')
      ->fields('c', array('cid'))
      ->condition('nid', $nids, 'IN')
      ->execute();
  $comments_count = $comments->rowCount();
  return $comments_count;
}
```